# Copying files through network c++

Tags: c++, file, copy

i,ve been trying to make a program that copies files through network to sync game saves between my PC and notebook whenever one of them updates. The problem is that when i run the program it just keeps "copying" and never ends. However, if i do it on the same pc with exactly the same file it does it instantly, i also tried sending a txt through the network and it worked just fine. Any ideas? Here is my code:

```
void copyFile() {
char x;
path PC = "C:\\Users\\Luciano\\Documents\\Sports Interactive\\Football Manager Touch 2017\\games\\River.fmt";
path Notebook = "Z:\\games\\River.fmt";
std::time_t lastWriteTo=0, lastWriteFrom=0;
if(exists(PC)){lastWriteFrom = last_write_time(PC);}
if(exists(Notebook)){lastWriteTo = last_write_time(Notebook);}  

if (lastWriteFrom > lastWriteTo || !exists(Notebook)) {
    std::cout << "Hay que copiar de la PC a la notebook" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Copiar Archivo? Este es de :" << (file_size(PC)/1024)/1024 << " Mb (S/N)" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> x;
    switch (x) {
    case 'S':
        std::cout << "Copiando Archivo..." << std::endl;
        try {
            copy_file(PC, Notebook, copy_option::overwrite_if_exists);
        }
        catch (filesystem_error &e) {
            std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        }
        break;
    case 's':
        std::cout << "Copiando Archivo..." << std::endl;
        try {
            copy_file(PC, Notebook, copy_option::overwrite_if_exists);
        }
        catch (filesystem_error &e) {
            std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        }
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Se ha cancelado la copia del archivo" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
}
else if(lastWriteFrom < lastWriteTo || !exists(PC)){
    std::cout << "Hay que copiar de la notebook a la PC" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Copiar Archivo? Este es de :"<< (file_size(PC) / 1024) / 1024 <<"(S/N)" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> x;
    switch (x) {
    case 'S':
        std::cout << "Copiando Archivo..." << std::endl;
        try {
            copy_file(Notebook, PC, copy_option::overwrite_if_exists);
        }
        catch (filesystem_error &e) {
            std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        }
        break;
    case 's':
        std::cout << "Copiando Archivo..." << std::endl;
        try {
            copy_file(Notebook, PC, copy_option::overwrite_if_exists);
        }
        catch (filesystem_error &e) {
            std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        }
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Se ha cancelado la copia del archivo" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
}else {
    std::cout << "No es necesario la copia del archivo." << std::endl;
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the copy_file function?

Comment: @Saustin Not sure but I think tht may be std::experimental::filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of things it could be, and without more information as far as what you've tried, here are some potential things:

- You have a locked file which cannot be read currently and your program doesn't know how to handle it. This is common with currently running programs in the directory, or if a different program calls [LockFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365202(v=vs.85).aspx). Are you running the game on the system you are trying to write to?
- Your permissions for reading/writing are messed up on either system.
- Your network or hard drive is really, really slow.
- You said you're using `std::experimental::filesystem`. This is experimental and might require some nontrivial intuition to use.

You say it keeps "copying forever." Is there any network traffic? Look using Wireshark or Resource Manager (task manager if Windows 10.)

Comment: I don't think its locked or that I don't have permission because I can move the file perfectly within my own PC. It could a speed problem be but I left it running at least for 10 minutes ( i have 100mbps speed). And I'm using the boost library not the std::experimental::filesystem. A friend said that there is a network buffer of max 1Mb do you know anything about that?

Comment: it just worked! it took about 20 minutes but it copied. any way to improve that speed?

Comment: Please accept the answer if you think it helped. To speed up network transfer, first ensure you are only transferring files that need to be transferred. You can calculate file hashes on both the client and server. If this optimization isn't enough, consider copying the files to a temporary directory then compressing them before sending them off. I would use xz since it is very good at compressing and you can tweak what tradeoff you want between performance and compression.